EXCEL FORMULA. version 2019
I am hitting a wall on my formula and don't know how to progress anymore. your help is much appreciated.
The table is complicated and submitted in this pattern, so i want to add a formula wherein the result will calculate if the parameters are met even the rows are multiple for a same salary but within the date range of SAP_MOSAL.
Parameters:

If SR_MOSAL is found in column SAP_MOSAL, then pass_1, if not then "FOR UPDATING"
if pass_1 then SR_FDATE must be within SAP_FDATE and SAP_TDATE, then pass_2, if not then "FOR UPDATING"
If Pass_1 and Pass_2 even with multiple rows, then "RETAIN"

Image:

a formula to solve this would be helpful :)

Post data as text table and show your desired output.

Welcome to the board.  Could you paste your sample data so that it can be copied and pasted for testing.  Something like the this will help to format the table:
https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#

Your description of the logic you want is incomprehensible. You will have to provide a concrete example of what you actually want as output. And input data as csv or tab delimited text please.

I would try with find() and if().

The formula in G2 and drag down.
If not 365 use only the inner function.
=LET(cnt,IF(SUMPRODUCT(IF((@Table2[SR_MOSAL]=Table2[SAP_MOSAL])*
(@Table2[SR_FDATE]>=Table2[SAP_FDATE])*
(@Table2[SR_FDATE]<=Table2[SAP_TDATE]),1,0))>0,"RETAIN","FOR UPDATING"),
cnt)

Inner function
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(IF((@Table2[SR_MOSAL]=Table2[SAP_MOSAL])*
(@Table2[SR_FDATE]>=Table2[SAP_FDATE])*
(@Table2[SR_FDATE]<=Table2[SAP_TDATE]),1,0))>0,"RETAIN","FOR UPDATING")



Definitely worth an upvote for working out what OP probably means.
